# How can we allow all users to view full details for meetings in an Exchange 2010 Resource Mailbox's calendar?

Tags: exchange-2010

We have Exchange 2010 with a number of resource mailboxes for various rooms. When user's view the room's calendar via the scheduling assistant they can only see if the room is busy or not, they can't see the meeting organiser or subject.

We want to make full details available for some rooms. For a normal user's calendar you just change the "Permissions" tab of the calendar's properties dialog. Would we need to do the same thing for a room's calendar, i.e. log on to a Windows PC, set up Outlook and then adjust the permissions? Or is there some PowerShell magic command I have not discovered?

Comment: You can't "log into" a room calendar in Exchange 2010, it's not possible.  Follow the powershell example below, it's what you want.

Comment: You *can* log into a room calendar in Exchange 2010. You can do this by granting full access permission on the calendar to a particular user. That user can then view the calendar's mailbox in the folders list in their regular Outlook profile, create a new Outlook profile for that calendar mailbox, or view the mailbox in OWA.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Exchange Management Shell:

```
Set-MailboxFolderPermission Room_Alias:\Calendar -User Default -AccessRights Reviewer
```

Substitute the room's Exchange Alias for "Room_Alias" above.

Comment: Could this command be tweaked to also work for giving say, a secretary, the ability to change meeting times/locations?

Comment: @ChrisPowell If you're looking for the ability to edit a room's schedule like people could in Exchange 2003, then no, that functionality no longer exists in 2007+. If you gave that secretary Full Access to the mailbox she could move meeting, but that moved meeting wouldn't be moved on the participants calendar, only on the room's calendar. Either the secretary needs to organize the meeting in the first place (so the "original organizer" can move the meeting) or you'd need 3rd party Meeting Organization software that provides this functionality.

Comment: Using the above works, but be aware that the folder names might be localized.

Comment: @ChrisS - This doesn't show the subject - it only shows the person who created the meeting.  Is that normal ?